# Difficulties with Paths for Security Group look-ups in AD with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, loops, path, active-directory, pipeline

I've been searching and tweaking a bit of PowerShell script for a few weeks.
My problem is that my folder paths have SPACES
And I need a clearer understanding of piping between one function and the next

This will work as long as $Folder is in quotes ("PATH"):

```
function Get-Permissions ($folder) {
(Get-Acl $Folder).Access | where-object {$_.IdentityReference -like "ABC\*" -and $_.IdentityReference -notlike "*FILE_SUPPORT*" -and $_.IdentityReference -notlike "*PRINT*"} | Select-Object -Property IdentityReference
}
```

I can enter: Get-Permissions "C:\My Drive\My Stuff\My Files"

I would like it work work  WITHOUT quotes, e.g. C:\My Drive\My Stuff\My Files

Next steps:

1. Somehow implement it to read a list of paths from a file

Apparently this is how to get quotes around each line:

```
(Get-Content $home\$user\appfiles\out.txt).ForEach({ '"{0}"' -f $_ })
```

How do I pipe this into Get-Acl?

2. As I need to use the Security Groups to provide access to a file or folder 4-5 levels down from the root, it would be useful to go up the directory tree:

File.txt is:

`\\ABC\My files1\My Stuff1\Gotta Get Here1`
`\\ABC\My files2\My Stuff2\Gotta Get Here2`

The output would be:

\ABC\My files1\My Stuff1\Gotta Get Here1
-Group1a
-Group2a
-Group3a

\ABC\My files1\My Stuff1
-Group1b
-Group2b
-Group3b

\ABC\My files1
-Group1c
-Group2c
-Group3c

\ABC\My files2\My Stuff2\Gotta Get Here2
-Group1c
-Group2c
-Group3c

\ABC\My files2\My Stuff2
-Group1d
-Group2d
-Group3d

\ABC\My files2
-Group1e
-Group2e
-Group3e

3. Right now, the function output is ABC\SOME-GROUP-NAME-X
   It would be nice to remove Domain ABC\ from the front.

I have tried using IdentityReference.TrimStart("ABC")
and some variations on @{label='Security Group';expression={$_.IdentityReference -replace '^ABC|,.*$'}}

Comment: The real problem here is SPACES.  $Folder is not read past the first space. Did a whole bunch of searching; not a single, straight forward "good" answer... :(

Comment: I really hoped someone would say *something* by now... Getting closer. This works with commas; how do I make the delimiter a space? ' function Get-Permissions {
[CmdletBinding()]
Param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
    [String[]]$folder
           ) Write-Output $folder}`

Comment: Can someone explain to me why it works at the prompt but not on the command line? `function Get-Permissions {
 [CmdletBinding()]
    Param (
       [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,HelpMessage="Enter a Folder Path!")]
 [ValidateNotNullorEmpty()]
 [string] $folder
    )`